# Bootstrap switch buttons don't work on mobile devices

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using an [amazing Bootstrap switch buttons](http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/) and can't figure out why checkboxes doesn't work properly on mobile devices (tested on Android 4.0 phone and iPhone 3G). Actually they are working, but a trigger action which displays a datepicker doesn't work at all :(

Here's a link: http://decart-design.com/365direkte/html5/

Here's a JS code for this switch button:

```
$('#mobile-order-form #statsborger1 input[type="checkbox"]').bind('change', function(){
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $('#statsborger2').slideUp(200);

        } else {
            $('#statsborger2').slideDown(200).find('input').focus();
            var datepicker = $('#statsborger2 input[type="text"]').data('Zebra_DatePicker');
            datepicker.show();
        }
    });
```

As you can see by browsing the [link above](http://decart-design.com/365direkte/html5/) on desktop the datepicker area appears when you click the first switch button. But this switch doesn't work on mobile browsers.

Could you please to figure out why it happens and what I'm doing wrong?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Works fine for me on a Nexus 4 running Jelly Bean 4.3 / Chrome 29

Comment: Yes, the switch buttons work. But try to click a first swicth button on desktop and you'll see a datepicker pop-up. On mobile device you just see how the switch works but any datepicker doesn't appear :(

Comment: It seems that the solution is found, a silly unclosed square brace :) Thanks everyone)

Comment: Strange, I was seeing the date picker on my mobile

Comment: Maybe the browser on your mobile phone ignored that error and displayed the datepicker. Anyway thank you for help Phil! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is found, a silly unclosed square brace :) Thanks everyone!